# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_Printer' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know why `print("Int to string: "+str(A_GLOBAL_INT_VARIABLE_CALLED_FROM_A_FUNCTION))` gives me this error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_Printer' objects` any help?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 96, in <module>
    gMenu()
  File "main.py", line 83, in gMenu
    terminalWarn("ACCOUNT DETAILS [DEBUG]:\n\nNickname: "+nickname+"\n\nExperiance: "+str(expe)+"\n\nLevel: "+str(level)+"\n\nCreator: "+creator+"\n\nCopyrights: "+copyright,"exit to menu")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_Printer' objects
```

(all variables defined in the error are ran in a function and are global.)

Comment: In gerneral don't use `+` on strings in Python, it is very inefficient. Instead use [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/).

Comment: Please show the function which you expect to return a int.

Comment: What are the types of `copyright`, `creator`, and `nickname`?

Comment: string, @kimbo its a string

Comment: One of the variables doesn't hold a string (although you think it does). You can use "print(repr(...))" to check what it is.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use str() for all the variables before concatenation within terminalWarn()

Comment: Use python string formatting. If you had, you'd at least know which item displays incorrectly. `terminalWarn("ACCOUNT DETAILS [DEBUG]:\n\nNickname: {}\n\nExperience: {}\n\nLevel: {}\n\nCreator: {}\n\nCopyrights: {}".format(nickname, expe, level, creator, copyright), "exit to menu")`

Comment: Nothing looks problematic in your code. To debug, try to remove variables one by one from the print statement and see when this error goes, this will get you the culprit (my gut feeling says `copyright` is a culprit) `2.` See if any copy-paste text or any special char is used in the message